# Instructions for making, and comparisons of, *small* solar thermal collectors

Tags: solar-power, home, diy, solar-thermal, statistics

The web has probably thousands of pages with instructions on how to build solar devices for heating air, water, and probably things I've never even thought of.

[Wikipedia describes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_thermal_collector) different types of thermal solar collectors, but really has a commercial focus.

However, when it comes to choosing an affordable design that might be useful for a DIY project at home (or for a small business), it's unclear exactly where to start looking and how to compare designs.

Are there any websites that act like a hub for this information and index or categorise the different techniques and devices?

For this question I'd like to focus, if possible, on finding a site that compares and rates different designs, as well as possibly providing instructions on building them.

Comment: Perhaps it will be too theoretical for you, but I just read that my alma mater is going to start a [free online course on Solar Energy on EdX.org](https://www.edx.org/course/delft-university-technology/et3034tux/solar-energy/770). The course description says *You will learn about the advantages, limitations and challenges of different solar cell technologies.... show you how to design a complete solar system for any particular application*. The course starts september 16th and anyone (with basic understanding of physics and mathematics) can follow it online.

Comment: @THelper, thanks for the link. That course is on photovoltaic technology, whereas this question is asking about specifically about thermal solar technology. Maybe though in a few years I'll be able to afford some PV panels at which point the course information will be of interest!

Comment: great question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excellent question, and I agree that much of the information is too focused on the commercial aspects. The best site I've found is http://www.builditsolar.com, which has extensive information on DIY solar thermal, along with a lot of project photos and links. The site organization may not be the best, but the content is outstanding.